# Potentiometer current rating

Tags: potentiometer, current-measurement

i am trying to control intensity of a 20-50W halogen lamp operating at 24V through a POT. my concerned is current passing through POT (which would be between 1A to 2.5A). what kind of POT should i look for? also how can i identify the POT's current rating?

Comment: Is the the supply a.c. or d.c? a.c. is better for the lamp and would allow you to use a phase control dimmer instead. If it is d.c. then you should consider a PWM control method for efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you will find a suitable potmeter. Standard carbon potmeters allow only a few mA, and even wirewound potmeters won't take 10 W. Because that's what we're talking about. The power dissipated in the potmeter will be at a maximum when the lamp power is set to 25%, but the current will be at a maximum when the lamp power is set to 99%. Also control is anything but linear.
A (linear or rotation) rheostat may work, but they're expensive and not easy to use.
I'd suggest to look for a low voltage dimmer, that's what they're for.